# Delete is not working in selected data at Datagrid view

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, sql-delete

I am trying to delete selected data from datagrid and database at the same time when user clicks on "Delete". It is not working and error message shows that "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index"
Can anyone help me out this coding.

```
private void btnDeleteCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strSqlConnection = @"Data Source = KK\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security = SSPI; Initial Catalog = JeanDB";

    if ((dgvCustomerView.Rows.Count>0) && (dgvCustomerView.SelectedRows[1].Index != dgvCustomerView.Rows.Count))
    {
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(strSqlConnection);


        DataSet dsCustomers = new DataSet();
        int iCustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(dgvEmpView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        string QueryDelCus = @"Delete from dbo.Customers WHERE CustomerID = @iCustomerID";
        SqlDataAdapter sdaCustomer = new SqlDataAdapter(QueryDelCus, sqlconn);

        sqlconn.Open();
        DataTable dtEmployee = new DataTable("Customers");
        sdaCustomer.Fill(dsCustomers, "Customers");
        sqlconn.Close();
        dgvEmpView.Rows.RemoveAt(dgvEmpView.SelectedRows[0].Index);
        MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to open and close the Connection object when using a DataAdapter.  It will open and close the connection for you.  You don't seem to be using dtEmployee.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **Remove** you can rebind grid:

```
dgvEmpView.DataSource = dsCustomers;
dgvEmpView.DataBind();
MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully");
```

and for deletion `ExecuteNonQuery` is used:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryDelCus, sqlconn);

sqlconn.Open();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have two rows selected referencing the SelectedRows[1] is wrong. The array indexes start always with zero. (Probably it is just a type because the other lines references correctly the row to be deleted)

```
if ((dgvCustomerView.Rows.Count>0) && 
    (dgvCustomerView.SelectedRows[0].Index != dgvCustomerView.Rows.Count))
{
    ....
```

but then, to delete the row in the database, you don't need to use an SqlDataAdapter. 
You could work directly with a SqlCommand

```
int iCustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(dgvEmpView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
string QueryDelCus = @"Delete from dbo.Customers WHERE CustomerID = @iCustomerID";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryDelCus, sqlconn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iCustomerID", iCustomerID);
sqlconn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

finally you could simply remove the selected row from the grid without further query

```
dgvEmpView.Rows.RemoveAt(dgvEmpView.SelectedRows[0].Index);
```

Answer (score 0):

If do not use sql parameters then use plain sql query.

```
DataSet dsCustomers = new DataSet();
int iCustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(dgvEmpView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
string QueryDelCus = @"Delete from dbo.Customers WHERE CustomerID = "+ iCustomerID.ToString();
SqlDataAdapter sdaCustomer = new SqlDataAdapter(QueryDelCus, sqlconn);
```